# Angular JS directive for number greater than 0

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, html, angularjs

I have the following input 
    `<input type="text" name="area" class="form-control" ng-pattern="onlyNumbers" ng-model="myForm.area" required>` and the ng-pattern only allows the input to have numbers.

```
$scope.onlyNumbers = /^\d+$/;
```

I also would like some way to tell the input that the number must be greater than 0. Meaning that the user must not input something like 023, it must be 23.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can just change the regex:

```
$scope.onlyNumbers = /^[1-9][0-9]*$/;
```

Answer (score 1):

Option allowing floats with `,` or `.` separators.

```
$scope.onlyNumbers = /^(0*[1-9][0-9]*([\.\,][0-9]+)?|0+[\.\,][0-9]*[1-9][0-9]*)$/;
```

Answer (score 0):

This will allow for any number above zero (eg, 0.0002).

`$scope.onlyNumbers = /^0*[1-9][0-9]*(\.[0-9]+)?|0+\.[0-9]*[1-9][0-9]*$/`

Comment: It allows to enter negative values, e.g.: `-0.1`